# junit - testing a private method of a class that is never instatiated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

So our stack is on `Spring`, and say Class `Wizard` is only ever called from a UI change. On the `xhtml` its called like this:

```
`<.....onchange="changeValue()" value="wizard.type.name">`
```

The class is never instantiated anywhere in the code, and the only constructor in the class is:

```
public Wizard(){}
```

And say `getName()` calls a private method `getWizardWeapon()` - how do i go about testing `getWizardWeapon()` in junit in a separate project (say `TestWizard` but in the same workspace)?

Comment: How about instantiate it in JUnit and use reflection? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes

Comment: test 'interface' which is visible outside of a class. So getName in this case. Otherwise you may couple test too much to your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't *have* to test private methods.  Tests should only go through the public interface methods.  So your tests should all go through `getName()`.

By not testing private methods, your tests are less fragile because if you ever changed your private method, the test would break.  It is so much easier to maintain and refactor classes knowing that modifying private methods shouldn't break anything as long as the public methods still do the right thing (which are all covered by tests).

From an API perspective I also find it weird that `getName()` also needs to `getWizardWeapon()`. unless the weapon is part of the name (which is weird).

If you can't exercise all code paths through your private methods by only calling public methods, maybe you have dead code that can be removed?

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @dkatzel answer: if you actually need to test some implementation details, but don't want to expose them to the outer world, make `getWizardWeapon()` not `private`, but `package private` and put your test cases in the same package (but of course in separate source directory like `main/com/example/Wizard` and `test/com/example/TestWizard`).